# I'm getting error using DataGrid Material UI component, it says "Can't resolve '@material-ui/x-license'", why?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've installed DataGrid Material UI in ReactJS using:

```
npm install @material-ui/data-grid
```

My code is very simple:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid />
        </div>
    );
}
```

But I'm getting that error:

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid/dist/index-esm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/x-license' in '/Users/m/Desktop/dev/market_average/market-average/node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid/dist'
```

Why? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The official code sandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pes12) also fails to run. However, there's a suggested fix in the error page:

> Add @material-ui/x-license as dependency

So simply edit `package.json` and add:

```json
"@material-ui/x-license": "4.0.0-alpha.36"
```

under the `dependencies` key.

---

**UPDATE**

The problem has been resolved with version `4.0.0-alpha.37` of `@material-ui/data-grid`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I installed x-license from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/x-license and it worked.

Comment: You can also use the prior version via `npm install @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.35`. I don't think the dependency on the x-license package was intentional.

Comment: `@material-ui/x-license` is not MIT, it has a commercial license https://unpkg.com/browse/@material-ui/x-license@4.0.0-alpha.36/LICENSE.md. Its usage is not allowed without a valid order. See https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/2291 for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

```
 npm install @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.35
```